# Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)dx \geq 0$ for every $k \geq 1$ given that $f$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given $f: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ convex function, prove that for every $k\geq1$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x) \cos (kx)dx \geq 0
\end{align}

I am completely stumped. What I have tried to do is return the query for $k=1$, and for that value of $k$ try to write the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ as a sum of four integrals from $0$ to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and use the [the theorem for first derivative monotony](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901753/continuity-of-derivative-of-convex-function). No luck so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:** I saw the link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191220/fourier-coefficient-of-convex-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) about a similarly asked topic. However, this process gets the general case as I perceive it and I am really supposed to use the method described above. I will try this and come back with a definitive answer.

**Edit 2:** I **cannot** use the $f''(x) \geq 0$ argument due to the simple fact that I have not been formally taught it as part of the class.

**Edit 3:** Final proof, with thanks to the contributors below.

Let's start by setting $A = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $B = \frac{3\pi}{2}$. It follows from basic trigonometry that:
\begin{align}
&\cos x \geq 0, \ x \in [A,B] \ \text{and}\\
&\cos x \leq 0, \ x \in [0, A] \cap [B, 2\pi].
\end{align}

And we also set $L$ to be the line segment such that $L(A) = f(A), \ L(B) = f(B)$. We will prove a basic property of said line in regards to the convex function $f$.

1. I can take for granted that (we proved this in class)
   \begin{align}
   L(x) = \dfrac{x-A}{B-A}f(B) + \dfrac{B-x}{B-A}f(A)
   \end{align}
   so for $x \in [A,B]$ there exists $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that: $x = \lambda A + (1-\lambda) B$. Taking the aforementioned expression and replacing it on $L(x)$ we get (I omit trivial algebra)
   \begin{align}
   L(x) = (1-\lambda) f(B) + \lambda f(A).
   \end{align}
   Since $f$ is convex, we can write
   \begin{align}
   &f(\lambda A + (1-\lambda) B) \leq \lambda f(A) + (1-\lambda) f(B)\\
   \implies &f(x) \leq L(x), \ \forall \ x \in [A,B] \ \text{and} \ \lambda \in [0,1].
   \end{align} $\blacksquare$
2. We assume that there exists $x \in [0,A]: \ f(x) < L(x)$. Then there exists $A \in [x, B] \ \text{and} \ \lambda \in [0,1]: \ A = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) B$. Then
   \begin{align}
   &L(A) = \dfrac{A-x}{B-x}f(B) + \dfrac{B-A}{B-x}f(x), \ A \in [x,B]\\
   \implies &L(A) = (1-\lambda)L(B)+\lambda L(x)\\
   \implies &L(A) = (1-\lambda)f(B) + \lambda L(x).
   \end{align}
   Then assuming that $L(x) > f(x)$ we get
   \begin{align}
   L(A) > (1-\lambda) f(B) + \lambda f(x) \geq f(A), \ \text{assuming convexity}.
   \end{align}
   Because $L(A) = f(A)$ the above inequality becomes $L(A) > f(A)$ which is a contradiction.

$\blacksquare$

In the same spirit, for $x \in [B, 2\pi]$ doing the exact same replacements and applying the exact same principles we also get
\begin{align}
&f(\lambda B + (1-\lambda) 2 \pi) \leq \lambda f(B) + (1-\lambda) f(2\pi)\\
\implies &f(x) \leq L(x).
\end{align}

$\blacksquare$

We then set $g(x) = f(x) - L(x)$ and from (1) and (2) above it is safe to assume that $\cos x$ and $g(x)$ will have the same sign in the whole domain, that is:
\begin{align}
&g(x) \geq 0, \ \text{where} \ \cos x \geq 0\\
&g(x) \leq 0, \ \text{where} \ \cos x \geq 0.
\end{align}

3. We have
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^{2\pi} g(x) \cos x dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} g(x) \cos x dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{2}} g(x) \cos x dx + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}g(x) \cos x dx \geq 0,
   \end{align}
   because
   \begin{align}
   &\text{in} \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right], \ \cos x \geq 0 \implies g(x) \geq 0\\
   &\text{in} \left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \right], \ \cos x \leq 0 \implies g(x) \leq 0\\
   &\text{in} \left[\frac{3 \pi}{2}, 2 \pi \right], \ \cos x \geq 0 \implies g(x) \geq 0.\\
   \end{align}
4. We have that
   \begin{align}
   &\int_0^{2 \pi}\cos x dx = 0 \ \text{trivial}\\
   &\int_0^{2 \pi}x \cos x dx = \int_0^{2 \pi}x (\sin x)' dx = \left[ x \sin x \right]_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin x dx = 0.
   \end{align}

It then follows that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) \cos x dx = \int_0^{2 \pi} g(x) \cos x dx \geq 0
\end{align}
which was previously proven. For the case $k=1$, the proof is over.

For $k>1$, we have:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}f(x) \cos (kx) dx = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \int_{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}^{\frac{2\pi (i+1)}{k}} f(x) \cos (kx) dx.
\end{align}
We perform the change of variable
\begin{align}
x = \dfrac{y+2\pi i}{k}\\
\implies \begin{cases}dx = \dfrac{1}{k}dy\\ x = \dfrac{2\pi i}{k} \to y=0\\ x = \dfrac{2\pi (i+1)}{k} \to y = 2\pi \end{cases}.
\end{align}
So the above sum becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{2\pi}f \left(\dfrac{y+2 \pi i}{k} \right) \cos (y+2\pi i)dy.
\end{align}
Because $f$ is convex in $[0, 2\pi]$ there exists $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that:
\begin{align}
 \theta f\left(\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 + (1 - \theta)f\left(\frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 &\ge f\left(\theta\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}
 + (1 - \theta) \frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)\\
 &= f\left(\frac{\theta y_1 + (1 - \theta)y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right).
\end{align}

Having performed the change of variables:
\begin{align}
x_1 = \dfrac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k} \ \text{and} \ x_2 = \dfrac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}.
\end{align}

So $f \left( \dfrac{y + 2\pi i}{k}\right)$ convex on $[0, 2\pi]$. Using the result from $k=1$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} f \left( \dfrac{y + 2\pi i}{k} \right)\cos y dy \geq 0.
\end{align}

$\blacksquare$

Comment: I would not really say so. The argument for this post assumes that f is twice differentiable but it's not universally guaranteed for my problem. Also, I am supposed to use the $k=1$ case to to break it up into 4 integrals and use the aforementioned theorem. Bottom line is it does help, but does not answer completely my question.

Comment: Now that I saw it, I am not really supposed to use the second derivative rule either. We have yet to be taught this and I am formally expected to use the original definition only.

Comment: One useful fact might be that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} (ax+b) \cos(kx) dx = 0$. And a convex function is like a straight line, but with the side bits (nearer the $0$ and $2\pi$) above the straight line.

Comment: That was also recommended by another user, but it's completely out of my course's scope.

Comment: Ah ok. Well if you really have to use the definition of convex then that seems quite a bit harder...

Comment: True that's why I ask here :)

Comment: The proofs of points 1. and 2. do not make much sense to me. For the point 1. you might start by saying that for $x\in[A, B]$ there is a $\lambda\in[0,1]$ such that $x=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$...

Comment: That's exactly the same thing I did albeit with different notation. It's already given that $f$ is convex so it's no problem starting right away with the inequality. Also, setting $x$ the way you did just serves to confuse me

Comment: For 
1. It's given that $f(x) \leq L(x)$, for every $x \in [A,B]$ so it will continue to stand for different choices of variables inside $[A,B]$ and by definition the conclusion follows.
2. Taking $x_0$ to disprove it, it's also pretty trivial, since we fix $x_0$ to a point and then leave $y$.

I don't really get what you are not getting.

Comment: If $\lambda\to0$, you will only get $f(y)\le f(y)$, that doesn't contradict anything.

Comment: Read better. It is for contradiction supposed that $f(x_0) < L$ and you have a strict inequality.

Comment: So what? Don't you know that when you go to the limit, you can't guarantee that the strict inequality will hold?

Comment: Again, it's all a matter of notation. If I wrote instead "$\lambda = 0$" would you be ok?

Comment: How do you justify $\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)\leq \lambda L(x) + (1-\lambda) L(x)$?

Comment: Because we set $f(x) \leq L(x)$ for every possible $x \in [A,B]$.

Comment: I think that by substituting $\lambda=0$, you will always get this kind of "contradiction", because the graph of a convex function always lies below the chord. Therefore, substituting the extreme values of the lambda by the definition of a convex function should be prohibited.

Comment: I am open to your approach for the contradiction. Please stop pointing out mistakes if you are not ready to give your view of the complete answer.

Comment: No. You defined $L$ as the straight line such that $L(A)=f(A)$ and $L(B)=f(B)$. Now, using the convexity of $f$ you want to prove that for all $x\in[A, B]$ you have that $f(x)\leq L(x)$. A priori you do not know that it is true (until you have proved it)...

Comment: @ECL you are right. Tell me how you would do it.

Comment: First, you have to convince yourself that $L(x) = \frac{x-A}{B-A}f(B) + \frac{B-x}{B-A}f(A)$ (it is linear in $x$ and it equals $f(A)$ in $A$ and $f(B)$ in $B$). Now, for $x\in[A, B]$, there is $\lambda\in[0,1]$ such that $x = \lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$. Now, you can explicitly find the value of $\lambda$ and show that $\frac{x-A}{B-A}=1-\lambda$ and $\frac{B-x}{B-A}=\lambda$, so that $L(x) = (1-\lambda)f(B) + \lambda f(A)$. Now use the convexity of $f$ and conclude.

Comment: Ok I will look into it when I get home and fix the original post.

Comment: The proof of (2) needs to be fixed as well. What I would do is to start by assuming that there is a $x\in [0,A]$ such that $f(x)<L(x)$. Then you have that $A\in [x,B]$ and so there is $\lambda\in[0,1]$ such that $A=\lambda x+(1−\lambda)B$. You can proceed in a very much similar way to what was done for point (1) and show that you must have $L(A)>f(A)$, which contradicts your definition of $L$. Analogously you can prove that for $x\in [B,2π]$ you must have $f(x)\leq L(x)$.

Comment: @ECL, I am typing the edit right now. How come you ended up with a strict inequality $L(A) > f(A)$, I am always ending up in the $\geq$.

Comment: @ECL, I have done the edits would you mind going over the question I posed above? Right now I am working for $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Of course this can fail when $k$ is not an integer.

Comment: Since $L$ is a straight line you have that if $A=(1-\lambda)B+\lambda x$, then $L(A) = (1-\lambda)L(B)+\lambda L(x)= (1-\lambda)f(B)+\lambda L(x)$ as $L(B)=f(B)$. If you assume that $L(x)>f(x)$, then $L(A)>(1-\lambda)f(B)+\lambda f(x)$. Now by convexity this is larger or equal to $f(A)$. But $L(A)=f(A)$ by definition of $L$, so you get that $f(A)>f(A)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @GEdgar Of course the property is false if $k$ is not an integer. (Take $f\equiv 1$ which is convex and $I=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(kx)dx\neq 0$  if $k$ is not an integer. If $I<0$ you have already a counterexample. If $I>0$, take $f\equiv -1$ and you find the counterexample).

Comment: @GEdgar of course it is. It is a common fact that for inductive proofs you take for granted that every $k$ is integer, so no problem.

Comment: @GEdgar also the bigger philosophical picture is that we take a line segment and "cut" it into infinitely many smaller units (that means by definition that they are in and of themselves "unhalvable" since there is no point in making fractions out of them) and try to find their area by integration. 

Bottom line is, not only is it common practice to take for granted that $k$ is integer always, it's also philosophically forced.

Comment: In my opinion, the word "integer" should be included in the statement of the problem.  In fact, you do not need the "$\;\ge 1$", it is true for $k=0$ and $k$ negative integer as well.

Comment: @GEdgar for $k=0$ you have $\cos(kx)=1$, but the integral of a convex function does not have to be non-negative.. (take $f\equiv -1$).

Comment: But I do agree that adding integer in the statement would be good.

Comment: I will give you that on my next edit and hopefully that would be the end of it.

Comment: @ECL finished the proof for $k=1$, tell me your thoughts. Later in the day I will go over $k>1$.

Comment: @ECL I finished the proof.

Comment: @River Li  I finished the proof.

Comment: @algevristis: Just in case that you are interested: I have posted a question about a possible generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4440563/42969 .

Comment: @MartinR very interesting. I will keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to give you some hints that can give you a proof using essentially only the definition of convexity.

Start by the case $k=1$. Denote $A=\pi/2$, $B=3\pi/2$, so that $\cos x\geq 0$ in $[A, B]$ and $\cos x\leq 0$ in $[0,A]\cap[B,2\pi]$. Let $L$ be the straight line such that $L(A)=f(A)$ and $L(B)=f(B)$.

1. Show that $f(x)\leq L(x)$ for all $x\in[A, B]$. (Hint: just apply the definition of convexity...)
2. Show that $f(x)\geq L(x)$ in $[0,A]\cap[B,2\pi]$. (Hint: assume that there is a point $x$ such that this is not true and try to find the contradiction...)

Now we can consider the function $g = f-L$. From the points (1) and (2) you have that, on $[0,2\pi]$, $g\geq 0$ where $\cos\geq 0$ and $g\leq 0$ where $\cos\leq 0$.

3. Conclude that $\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)\cos x dx\geq 0$.
4. Show that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos x dx=\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)\cos x dx$. (Hint: first show that $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x dx=0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}x\cos x dx=0$...)

Now you need to consider the generic case $k\geq 1$. However this follows from the case $k=1$. The idea is that we can split $[0, 2\pi]$ in $k$ intervals of length $2\pi/k$. Now let $[a, b]$ be one of this intervals, that is for some integer $0\leq m<k$ you have $ak=2m\pi$ and $bk=2(m+1)\pi$. We need to show that $\int_a^b \cos(kx)f(x)dx\geq 0$.

5. Show that $\int_a^b \cos(kx)f(x)dx = \frac{1}{k}\int_0^{2\pi}f\left(a+x/k\right)\cos(x)dx$. (Hint: this is just a change of variable...)
6. Show that $x\mapsto f\left(a+x/k\right)$ is convex and conclude that $\int_a^b \cos(kx)f(x)dx\geq 0$.
7. Show that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)dx\geq 0$.

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Nice :) Now the answer seems pretty good. It's amazing that it's so simple.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it should be $\cos x\leq 0$ in $[A, B]$ and $\cos x\geq 0$ in $[0,A]\cup[B,2\pi]$. Also $f(x) \ge L(x)$ in $[0,A]\cup[B,2\pi]$.

Comment: Since $\cos(0)=1$, cos is positive in $[0,A]$, not negative. The sign is similarly reversed in the other intervals.

Answer (score 3):

The proof using twice integration by parts requires differentiability of $f.$ Instead we can use summation by parts as follows. The integral in question is the limit of Riemann sums
$$S_n:={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n f\left ({2\pi j\over n}\right )\cos {2\pi k j\over n}$$ It  suffices to show that $\lim S_n\ge 0.$

Observe that $$2\sin{\pi k \over n}\cos{2\pi kj\over n}=\sin {2\pi k(j+{1\over 2}) \over n}-\sin {2\pi k(j-{1\over 2}) \over n}$$
Therefore denoting $a_j=f\left ({2\pi j\over n}\right )$ and
$b_j=\sin {2\pi k(j+{1\over 2}) \over n}$
leads to
$$2n\sin\ {\pi k \over n}\ S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j(b_j-b_{j-1})
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (a_j-a_{j+1})b_j +a_{n}b_n-a_0b_0\\
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (a_j-a_{j+1})b_j+[f(1)-f(0)]\,\sin{\pi k\over n}
$$
We have
$$ 2\sin {\pi k \over n}\cdot b_j=\left [1-\cos{2\pi k (j+1)\over n}\right ]-\left [1-\cos{2\pi k j\over n}\right ]$$
Hence denoting $\Delta a_j=a_j-a_{j+1},$  $c_j=1-\cos{2\pi k j\over n}$  and observing that $c_0=c_n=0$ gives
$$ 4n\sin^2{\pi k\over n} \ S_n= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\Delta a_j\,[c_{j+1}-c_{j}]+ 2[f(1)-f(0)]\,\sin^2{\pi k\over n}\\
= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [\Delta a_{j-1}-\Delta a_j]c_j+\Delta a_{n-1}\,c_n-\Delta a_0\,c_0 +  2[f(1)-f(0)]\,\sin^2{\pi k\over n}\\
= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [\Delta a_{j-1}-\Delta a_j]c_j+ 2[f(1)-f(0)]\,\sin^2{\pi k\over n}$$
Summarizing
$$S_n={1\over 4n\sin^2{\pi k\over n}} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [\Delta a_{j-1}-\Delta a_j]c_j+{1\over 2n}[f(1)-f(0)]$$
The sum is nonnegative as $c_j\ge 0$ and $\Delta a_{j-1}-\Delta a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j+1}-2a_j\ge 0$, by the convexity of $f$.  Hence  $\lim S_n$ is nonnegative.

Comment: (+1) Nice use of trig. identities here.

Comment: Thanks, also for editing.

Answer (score 3):

As demonstrated in the other answers, it suffices to prove the statement for $k=1$, that is
$$
 I = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x) \cos (x) \, dx \ge 0 \, .
$$
We can split the integral into four parts over the intervals $[0, \pi/2]$, $\pi/2, \pi]$, $[\pi , 3\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/2, 2 \pi|$ and substitute $x = \pi - y$, $x=\pi + y$, $x =2\pi -y$ in the second, third, and fourth integral, respectively. This gives
$$
 I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \bigl( f(x) - f(\pi -x) - f(\pi + x) + f(2\pi - x)\bigr) \cos(x) \, dx \, .
$$
So order to prove $I \ge 0$ it suffices to show that
$$ \tag{$*$}
f(\pi -x) + f(\pi + x) \le f(x) + f(2\pi - x) 
$$
for $0 \le x \le \pi/2$.

And that follows directly from the convexity condition, applied to $x < \pi - x< 2 \pi-x$:
$$
 f(\pi - x) \le \frac{\pi}{2 \pi - 2x}f(x) + \frac{\pi - 2x}{2 \pi - 2x}f(2\pi - x) \, ,
$$
and to $x < \pi + x < 2 \pi-x$:
$$
 f(\pi + x) \le \frac{\pi-2x}{2 \pi - 2x}f(x) + \frac{\pi}{2 \pi - 2x}f(2\pi - x) \, .
$$
Adding these two inequalities gives exactly $(*)$, and that finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Supplement to @ECL's answer**:

1. For $k = 1$:

Let
$$g(x) := f(x) - \frac{f(3\pi/2) - f(\pi/2)}{\pi}x - \frac{\frac{3\pi}{2}f(\pi/2) - \frac{\pi}{2}f(3\pi/2)}{\pi}.$$

We have $g(\pi/2) = g(3\pi/2) = 0$.
Also, $g(x)$ is convex on $[0, 2\pi]$.

For $x \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$, letting $t = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{x}{\pi} \in [0, 1]$, we have $x = \frac{\pi}{2} t 
+ \frac{3\pi}{2}(1 - t)$ and
$$g(x) \le t g(\pi/2) + (1 - t)g(3\pi/2)  = 0.$$

For $x\in [0, \pi/2]$, using $\pi - x \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ and $g(x) + g(\pi - x) \ge 2g(\pi/2) = 0$, we have
$$g(x) \ge -g(\pi - x) \ge 0.$$

For $x\in [3\pi/2, 2\pi]$, using $3\pi - x\in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ and $g(x) + g(3\pi - x) \ge 2g(3\pi/2) = 0$, we have
$$g(x) \ge -g(3\pi - x) \ge 0.$$

Using $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos x \mathrm{d} x = 0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} x \cos x \mathrm{d} x = 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos x \mathrm{d} x\\
 =\,& \int_0^{2\pi} g(x)\cos x \mathrm{d} x\\
 =\,& \int_0^{\pi/2} g(x)\cos x \mathrm{d} x
 + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} g(x)\cos x \mathrm{d} x
 + \int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi} g(x)\cos x \mathrm{d} x\\
  \ge\,& 0.
\end{align*}

$\phantom{2}$

2. For $k > 1$:

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\cos k x \mathrm{d} x\\
 =\,& \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \int_{2\pi i/k}^{2\pi(i + 1)/k} f(x)\cos k x \,\mathrm{d} x\\
 =\,& \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k}\int_0^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{y + 2\pi i}{k}\right)\cos y\, \mathrm{d} y.
\end{align*}

For any $y_1, y_2 \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0, 1]$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \theta f\left(\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 + (1 - \theta)f\left(\frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 &\ge f\left(\theta\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}
 + (1 - \theta) \frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)\\
 &= f\left(\frac{\theta y_1 + (1 - \theta)y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right).
\end{align*}
Thus, $f\left(\frac{y + 2\pi i}{k}\right)$ is convex on $[0, 2\pi]$.

Using the result for $k = 1$, we have
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f\left(\frac{y + 2\pi i}{k}\right)\cos y \,\mathrm{d} y \ge 0.$$

The desired result follows.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\begin{align*}
 \theta f\left(\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 + (1 - \theta)f\left(\frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)
 &\ge f\left(\theta\frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}
 + (1 - \theta) \frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right)\\
 &= f\left(\frac{\theta y_1 + (1 - \theta)y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}\right).
\end{align*}$

Comment: @algevristis Denote $x_1 = \frac{y_1 + 2\pi i}{k}$ and $x_2 = \frac{y_2 + 2\pi i}{k}$. Since $f(x)$ is convex, we have $\theta f(x_1) + (1-\theta) f(x_2) \ge f(\theta x_1 + (1 - \theta)x_2)$.

Comment: Damn I am completely blind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @algevristis You are welcome.

Comment: I would skip the proof that if $f(x)$ is convex so is $f(ax+b).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I wrote down the proof that $f\left(\frac{y + 2\pi i}{k}\right)$ is convex, because I saw a user commented on ECL's answer to ask why $x\mapsto f\left(a+x/k\right)$ is convex (the user deleted this comment later, perhaps after I posted my answer).

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I wrote down my answer to help some people to understand ECL's answer. As you see now, there are 28 comments on OP, some of them related to understanding ECL's answer.

Comment: @River Ok. But I would rather mention that the composition of two convex functions $f(g(x))$  is again convex, $g(x)=ax+b$ in particular. When you make use of special values of $a=1/k$ and $b$ some users may think that the conclusion depends on these values

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You are absolutely right. But perhaps it is unkind to some audience. So I keep it.

Comment: Just in case that you are interested: I have posted a question about a possible generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4440563/42969 .

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for information.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $[0,2\pi].$ Then
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)\,dx=\left. f(x)\frac {\sin(kx)} k\right |_0^{2\pi} -\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x)\frac {\sin(kx)} k\,dx= -\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x) \frac {\sin(kx)} k\,dx.$$
Next, again integraiting by parts, this equals
$$\left. f'(x)\frac {\cos(kx)} k\right|_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cos(kx)\,dx\ge$$ $$f'(2\pi)-f'(1)-\int_0^{2\pi}f''(x)\cdot1\,dx= $$ $$f'(2\pi)-f'(1)-\int_0^{2\pi} f''(x)\,dx=0 $$ since the second derivative of a convex function is nonnegative. The general case is obtained by approximation of $f(x)$ by a smooth function with precision  $\epsilon$, making use of convolution, and then by taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0+$.

Comment: Basically the same solution ($f\in C^2([0,2\pi])$ was posted by the late Julian Aguirre [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1191241/121671).

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Thank you for the reference. As Koran says,  prayer does not spoil from repetition.