# Show $\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos(ax) dx \ge 0$ if $f$ is convex and $a \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let  $f$ be a convex function and $a \in \mathbb R$.
Is it true that
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos(ax) dx \ge 0$$
holds? Of course, this would be true if we replaced $\cos$ by $|\cos|$, but I guess that the convexity of $f$ may compensate for the oscillations of $\cos$. Is it true?

Comment: The integral need not exist. (e.g. $f(x)=1$).

Comment: @Jun if f is negative, this fails.

Comment: You need to add some assumptions so that the integral is convergent. For example $f(x)$ could be decreasing and with limit $0$ at $\infty$ and $a\neq 0.$

Comment: A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4414089/121671) was solved here by Ryszard Szwarc when integration is done over a particular interval.