# Integral inequality with convex function

Tags: calculus, integral-inequality

Here is a problem for solving it there is enough knowledge in the volume of 1-2 courses of mathematical specialties. I managed to do this, perhaps because the proof is not based on some kind of focus, but is short (a few lines), logical and consistent, although it requires a certain courage of thought. If a function $f(x)$ is convex on the segment from zero to two pi, then the inequality $$\forall n, n\in \mathbb N,\,  \int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx \ge 0 $$ holds. In the above $0$ is not treated as a natural number.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to prove it? Maybe, there are few ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(kx)dx \geq 0$ for every $k \geq 1$ given that $f$ is convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414089/prove-that-int-02-pifx-coskxdx-geq-0-for-every-k-geq-1-given-tha)

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Thank you for the reference. My proof is not tricky and the one is simpler in the case $f\in C^2[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I presented my answer in the thread inidcating by you.